# class.getResourceAsStream('*.groovy')

Tags: groovy, nullpointerexception, gradle

I have graddle project and I have faced with next issue.
I try to copy groove scripts under resource package to another place. But during this process I alway get NullPointerException.

I tried to get resource stream following ways:

1. class.getResourceAsStream("*.groovy")
2. class.getClassLoader().getResourceAsStream("*.groovy")

Always result was the same.
Actually for all other resource types("*.txt"..) all works properly.

My source tree:
**src**
 groovy/com.....
**resources**
scripts
/deploy.groovy

Update: I use intellij idea as IDE

Thanks in advance for all suggestions

Comment: You're actually trying `*.groovy`? I can't imagine that using wildcards would *ever* work. (Also, post a directory listing of your source tree. Groovy scripts aren't generally in `resources`.)

Comment: Sorry, actually it means each file with groovy extension

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have your Groovy scripts compiled as classes and not added to the jar as resources.

Check the jar files that where created.

Comment: Thanks, Actually at groovy compiler I have add resource folder for exclusion and all start working fine.